# Assign function options from anonymous function results

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to assign the "collapsible" option for a JQuery accordion by determining whether the accordion container has a particular class assigned.

So `<div class="accordion">....</div>` should use the default, but `<div class="accordion collapsible">....</div>` should be collapsible. I thought I could use a function result for the option, but I'm not sure which object I need to call to get a hold of the div's "hasClass()" function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("div.accordion").accordion(
{
    active: 0, autoHeight: false, header: "table.xxx",
    collapsible : function() { return myDivsObject.hasClass("collapsible") }()
 }
 );
```

It'd be great if you could help me on how to pass or access the correct object (ie the replacement for `myDivsObject` above) - I've tried around with `this` and `$(this)` to no avail, and also tried about 500 other variations.
Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
$("div.accordion").each(function() {

var curAccordian = this;
$(curAccordian).accordion(
{
    active: 0, autoHeight: false, header: "table.xxx",
    collapsible : $(curAccordian).hasClass("collapsible")
 });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! Is there a benefit to assign this to a variable? Or could I write it without loss of speed or performance as this.accordion(.... collapsible: this.hasClass("collapsible") as well?